# Get text from id in html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

i got the below html code

```
<div class="SB-marketBox SB-accordion ">
    <div class="SB-marketBox-header SB-accordion-header SB-arrowAfter" id="market_140" onclick="getMarketAccordian('market_140')">
        <div class="SB-marketName"><span>Second Half Goals – odd/even</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="SB-accordion-content">
        <div class="SB-marketBox-content">
            <ul class="SB-marketOutComeOddsList ">
                <li>
    <button class="btn SB-btnOdds SB-btnOutComeOdds " individualevent-odds-incdec='N' id='highlightBet_79233205' >
        <div class="SB-outcome-container">
            <span class="SB-outcome">Even</span>            
        </div>
        <div class="SB-odds">1.80</div>
    </button>
</li>
<li>
    <button class="btn SB-btnOdds SB-btnOutComeOdds " individualevent-odds-incdec='N' id='highlightBet_79233206' >
        <div class="SB-outcome-container">
            <span class="SB-outcome">Odd</span>            
        </div>
        <div class="SB-odds">1.90</div>
    </button>
</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to extract the  id for Even and Odd outcome have written a python script below to solve it

```
item = soup.find(class_='SB-marketBox SB-accordion')   
Even = item.find_all(class_='SB-odds')[0].get_text()
Odd = item.find_all(class_='SB-odds')[1].get_text()
Even_id = item.find_all(id)[0].get_text()
Odd_id = item.find_all(id)[1].get_text()

print(f'{Even} {Even_id} {Odd} {Odd_id}')
```

Am getting IndexError: list index out of range. How can I modify the code to get the id for odd and even

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
btn_even = soup.select_one('button:has(span:-soup-contains("Even"))')
btn_odd = soup.select_one('button:has(span:-soup-contains("Odd"))')

print(btn_even["id"], btn_even.select_one(".SB-odds").text)
print(btn_odd["id"], btn_odd.select_one(".SB-odds").text)
```

Prints:

```
highlightBet_79233205 1.80
highlightBet_79233206 1.90
```